# No detection when using AprilTags

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I am trying to use the Apriltag package in ros 2 (humble) using this repo (https://github.com/christianrauch/apriltag_ros). I have published both rgb camera and mono camera to that package. When I echoed the /detection and /tf topics, there is no data came up on my screen. I used 36h11 family of tag. Does anyone know how to solve this ?